# Center content div using 960 grid system

Tags: css, frameworks, 960.gs

This sounds easy but. I am simply not able to do it. Here is what I have:

```
<h1>Head </h1>
<div class="container_12" >
    <div class="grid_6">
        <h1>Heading one</h1>
        <p>Content and Images</p>
    </div>
        <h1>Heading two</h1>
        <p>Content and Images</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_12">The footer</div>
    </div>
<body>
</body>
```

I need the divs with `grid_6` to vertically aligned in middle for any type of screen. It seems the main div with `container_12` just doesn't take the page's full height!? How can I have the content div float in middle of the screen?

Comment: you want it horizontally **and** vertically centered?

Comment: the framework makes sure its horizontally centered.. i need it vertical..

Comment: also note that its not the contents of the div.. as a whole the divs should be in middle..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give id to your content div

```
var screenheight = document.body.clientHeight;
var content_div_height = document.getElementById("content_div_id").offsetHeight;
var content_div_top = (screenheight/2) - (content_div_height/2)
document.getElementById("content_div_id").style.top = content_div_top + 'px';
```

Comment: seriously, I was expecting an CSS solution.. let me check this out!

Comment: for vertical alignment you have to give the top position, for purely css solution make body a fixed height then assign top position to content div

Comment: Thanks! got it working as per my requirement.. your code was a starting point :)

Answer (score -1):

```
*{  
   margin:0;  
   padding:0;  
}  

body{  
   text-align:center; /*For IE6 Shenanigans*/  
}  

#wrapper{  
   width:960px;  
   margin:0 auto;  
   text-align:left;  
}
```

Comment: Can't see that this would have any affect on vertical alignment

Comment: OP is asking for "vertical alignment" not horizontal.